# What is the best framework for desktop applets to begin with?

Tags: applet, desktop-application, cappuccino

I would like to make a simple desktop application to learn this kind of thing.

What language would you recommend for beginner? 
Would you recommend using framework for beginners?
I'm experienced only in javascript and little bit of PHP.

What do you say about cappuccino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the Yahoo widgets system, as you are experienced in Javascript.
It is fully Javascript based. (with a little HTML I believe)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I also checked Google Desktop gadgets and since I use Google services more than Yahoo!, I'll probably try that first

Answer (score 0):

I recommend python + PyQt. Very easy to learn, very powerful.